# C: Cant display linked list values

Tags: c, function, pointers, while-loop, linked-list

So I'm making a linked list with 3 nodes, and right now I'm trying to implement a function that displays the list in C , here is the code :

```
struct node *createList(struct node *start)
{
    int i, n, data;


    printf("Enter the number of nodes :  ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n==0)
        return start;

    printf("Enter the first element to be inserted :  ");

    scanf("%d", &data);

    printf("%d",data);

    start=insertInBeginning(start, data);

    for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the next element to be inserted : ");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insertAtEnd(start, data);
    }
    return start;
}

// end of createList


struct node *insertInBeginning(struct node *start, int data) 
{
    printf("we in begining \n");

    struct node *new_node,*current;

    printf("declared nodes");

    new_node = &data;

    printf("got new_node data \n");

    if(start == NULL) {

        printf("start is null! \n");

        start = new_node;

        current = new_node;

    } else {
        printf("start isn't null!  \n");

        new_node->link=start;

        start=new_node;
    }

}

//end of insertInBeginning


void insertAtEnd(struct node *start, int data)
{
struct node *new_node,*current,*temp;

new_node->info = data;
if(start == NULL)
 {

start= new_node;
current= new_node;

} else 
{
    temp = start;

    while(temp->link!=NULL) {
        temp =  temp->link;
    }
    temp -> link = new_node;
}


}

// end of insertAtEnd



void displayList(struct node *start)
{

    printf("we in displaylist");
    struct node *temp;

    temp = start->link;
    printf("temp has start values?");

    if(temp = NULL)
    {
    printf("we null now \n");
    } else {
    printf("we NOT null \n" );
    while(temp!=NULL) 
    {
    printf("%d \n",temp->info);
    temp = temp->link;
    }
}
}
```

The  problem that I am having is that the in the display function the loop completes and but it doesnt print any of the values, however i know that temp is not NULL so it is displaying something, just not what i want, is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: 'insertInBeginning' does not actually return anything, despite its profile:(   I'm really surprised that you got no warnings for that.  Really surprised.

Comment: in insertInBeginning , new_node = &data , I think what you are trying to do is new_node->info = data;

Comment: @d_void i think i tried this, and it ended up crashing my program, so I dont know how to fix that :/

Comment: @MartinJames so what exactly should i do here? what should i return?the tutorial i followed didn't have a return statement, so I don't know what i could be doing wrong...

Comment: @Ventus: So drop that tutorial and get a good C book. Obscure online tutorials, youtube videos and blogs are not suitable to learn C.

Comment: Please pick one, and *only one* [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) for all code used in a project (here, a question). Use that *one* style consistently throughout all of the code for a project. Doing so makes is *much* easier to read/maintain code. Not doing so results in the people reading it having to put out extra effort to help you. While there are many opinions on which indent style is the best style to use, the important thing is to *pick one and **use it consistently*** throughout a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big problems here: firstly, (as Martin James points out), you don't have a return from your insertInBeginning() routine, so start is set to some undefined value.  You also have a huge problem that you are just casting `int data` to a `node *`.  You must malloc() memory for the new node and write data into it.  (And then return it) You have the same issue in your insertAtEnd() routine--you must malloc() memory to hold the new node.

```
static struct node *
insertAtStart (struct node *start, int data)
{
    struct node *new;

    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    if (new == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }

   new->value = data;
   new->next = start;
   return new;
}

static struct node *
insertAtEnd (struct node *start, int data)
{
    struct node *cur, *new;

    // create the node * we will be adding.  (This really ought to have been done
    // in the calling routine, so the same code would be used to create the node
    // entry and to store the value.  Note a big issue with this simple a struct,
    // but more complex structs really ought to only be created in one place, so
    // when they change, you won't have bugs where you forget to change one of 
    // the creation locations)
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    if (new == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    new->value = data;
    new->link = NULL;

    // if this is going to be the only entry in the list, just return that it 
    // is the new start
    if (start == NULL) 
        return new;

    // find the last entry
    for (cur = start ; cur->link != NULL ; cur = cur->link)
        ;
    cur->link = new;
    return start;
}
```

You really want to turn on compiler warnings--it saves a lot of time to have the compiler tell you about these sorts of errors.  If you are using gcc, add -Wall -Werror to your compile command (if you are using a different compiler, you'll need to read the man page).

(There are other gcc warnings that you can turn on, but -Wall gets you a lot of useful ones.  You can read the man page to find all the ones you want if you want to turn on more)

Comment: ill try this out very soon, however is it possible to post an example? I wanna make sure i do this correctly.if not thats ok.Also im assuming i return my linked list start correct?I also notice that my while loop in insertAtEnd is  infinte, so I'm currently trying to solve that as well, advice for that would also be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: The insertAtStart() routine given in my code sample ought to work (you just need to change the new->value and new->next pointers to the correct variable names for your struct; new->info and new->link I believe are the variable names you used.  You are mistaken, you do not have an infinite loop in insertAtEnd(), but you do have a bug if it is called with start == NULL: you never return start, so your code will not see that there is now an element on your linked list.

Comment: So, i got the insert at start to work,still having trouble with insertAtEnd(). i removed the if statement that had start== NULL but it still gives me the same result. any help with this function?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an insertAtEnd() function.  Note that your call on it will have to be `start = insertAtEnd(start, data)` so you set start in the case that you are inserting to an empty linked list.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it seems to have put me in an infinite loop at the where the for loop is, meaning that i im not getting to NULL, will check my code to see if i made a mistake.

Comment: If it is in an infinite loop, then there was an error before it that resulted in a node entry's link pointer pointing backwards (or to itself most likely).  Doing a `printf("%p\n", cur)` in the for() loop will probably show you the problem quickly.

Comment: Why must he use `malloc`, if functions like `scanf` can perform the same (kind of) task and don't need `malloc`? I'm sorry, but I think this answer could be better...

Comment: Think about this: When you ask `scanf` for a `void *`, by providing it with the `%p` format deligate and passing a corresponding pointer-to-`void *` (i.e. `void *ptr; scanf("%p", &ptr);`), `scanf` *isn't* allocating any memory, right? `scanf` receives all of the memory it needs in the form of a pointer provided by the unary `&` address-of operator, right? Your function, the *caller of `scanf`*, can see the changes that `scanf` made to that pointed-to-object, yes? I encourage trying to program like this. you might notice something about how *easy* it becomes to write clean test harnesses ;)

Comment: That makes no sense at all.  scanf() is doing something very different; it has all the memory it needs because you pass in the address of the pointer it is to store into (if you really want to compare to scanf(), the difference between %s and %as is far more apt--and the reason scanf() can do the %as function is that it does the malloc for you).  This case is completely different--he needs a pointer to a struct, so he needs to allocate memory to hold the struct.  He cannot just declare it on the stack because then the memory will be reused when he returns from the function.

Comment: @Jabberwock I tried what you suggested, and it gave me an infinite loop but this time it listed i think 2 memory locations, how do I solve this? P.S: sorry to say but im a serious beginner at this, this is my first time using linked list and i haven't used C in a while, so apologizes for all the questions.

Comment: So it just repeats two things over and over?  That suggests that the error came when you added the second item.  The second item's link pointer needed to be set to NULL (if added to the end of the linked list); are you sure you have the `new->link = NULL;` line included?  If it is repeating the same two over and over, it looks like you did `new->link = start;` which would cause the endless loop.  The goal is to have the linked list look like [node0]->[node1]->NULL.

Comment: @Jabberwock, i cant believe it, it worked, its displaying right now, thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Answer (score -1):

As said the insertion function has some troubles. 
This code declares the struct `node` **once**:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
struct node{int info; node* next; node(int a=0, node* b=0){info=a; next=b;}}; // field1->value field2->next node
```

This "declaration" guarantees that nodes created have defined values.
The function that creates a simple list that has dim values:

```
node* build_L(int dim)
{
 if(dim)
   {int x; cin>>x; return new node(x,build_L(dim-1));}
 return 0;
}
```

And printing:

```
 void pr_L(node*L)
{
 if(L)
  {cout<<L->info<<' '; pr_L(L->next);}
 else
   cout<<endl;

}
```

Add node at the beginning:

```
node*insB(node*L,int k)
{
  node* n=new node(k,L);
  return n;
}
```

In the end:

```
 node* insE(node*L, int k)
            {
            node*temp=L;
            while(L->next)
            {
            L=L->next;
            }
            node*e=new node(k,0);
            L->next=e;
            L=temp;
            return L;
            }
```

In the `main` you can invoke the functions:

```
 main()
    {
       int dim_list;//set the number of nodes 

       cin>>dim_list;
    //or scanf()
       node*L=build_L(dim_list);

       cout<<"List built"<<endl;
    //or printf() 

    pr_list(L);
   int k,f; cin>>k;
    L=insB(L,k);
    cout<<"node in first position: "<<endl;
    pr_L(L);
    cin>>f;
    L=insE(L,f);
    cout<<"node in queue: "<<endl;
    pr_L(L);
    }
```